# Ionic app is “restarted” when I move it to background

Tags: android, visual-studio, ionic-framework, background

Im creating an app and I need to **keep working in background** but this doesnt work.
Im using:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

I am on **Visual studio with ionic** , so I execute:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

The app is launched and working. The first view is a Login, I fill the login and this take me to the second view (thit is a tab page).
On this page I add:

```
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';

constructor(private background: BackgroundMode){
this.background.enable();
console.log(this.background.isEnable());
console.log(this.background.isActive());
this.background.moveToBackground();
}
```

Also, `console.log` shows that is enable, but not active (that is normal).

The problem is that **when I move the app to the background, is “restarted”** . I mean that when I open the app from the background it takes me again to the first view where I should do the Login. So this is not working.

[This image appears all the times that I open the app for background, and after this, the app is restarted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRxNY.jpg)

Am I doing something wrong? Is visual studio?** How can I solve it?**

**Thanks!**

Comment: Did you found a solution? I am also stucked here.

Comment: Also looking for a solution, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Use plugin Background Mode

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode

npm install @ionic-native/background-mode
```

Then use it like this:

```
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode) {
        this.initializeApp();
    }

    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.backgroundMode.enable();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! thanks on first place. But shuld I use on AppComponent.ts or in the tab.ts of my project?

Comment: I added this, but isnt working. I can move the app to background, but when I take it to foreground is "restarted"

Comment: @LolaCols you must use it in app.component.ts

Comment: @LolaCols can I see your config.xml?